# How can I estimate the shape and scale of a gamma dist. with a particular mean and a 95% quantile?

Tags: r, statistics, gamma-distribution

Is there any way, in R, to calculate the scale and shape of a gamma distribution, given a particular value of mean (or median) and a particular quantile (the 95% quantile)?

So for example I have a **mean = 130**

and a **95% quantile = 300**

with an **offset** of the distribution at **80**

is there any way to obtain the scale and shape of a gamma that meet these criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
myfun <- function(shape) {
    scale <- 130/shape
    pgamma(300, shape, scale=scale) - 0.95
}

tmp <- uniroot( myfun, lower=2, upper=10 )

myshape <- tmp$root
myscale <- 130/tmp$root

qgamma(0.95, shape=myshape, scale=myscale)
integrate( function(x) x*dgamma(x,shape=myshape,scale=myscale), 
    lower=0, upper=Inf )
```

I am not sure what you mean by offset of 80, if that is just where the gamma becomes non-zero then subtract 80 from 130 and 300 and do the same as above.

Comment: thank you, it seems though that for some combinations of numbers (for example: mean =8, quartile 95% = 32) this isnt working, it gives an error such as: Error in uniroot(myfun, lower = 2, upper = 10) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign

Comment: @user18441, you need to give it starting values that bracket the answer, meaning one of them returns a postive value from `myfun` and the other a negative.  Try a few values and see what you get, then choose 2 for the starting values.  See `?uniroot` for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `optim()` function to simultaneously fit the two parameters of the distribution:

```r
offset <- 80
x <- c(q50 = 130, q95 = 300) - offset # Subtract offset and re-add later.
expected <- c(0.5, 0.95)

gamma_fit_error <- function(params) {
  with(as.list(params), {
    mat <- t(matrix(c(x,
                      qgamma(expected, shape = shape, scale = scale)),
                    nrow = length(x)))
    c(dist(mat))
  })
}

opt <- optim(par = c(shape = 1, scale = 10),
             fn = gamma_fit_error,
             method = "L-BFGS-B",
             lower = c(shape = 0.1, scale = 1),
             upper = c(shape = 100, scale = 100))
```

The `fn` input to `optim()` requires a single `params` input from which we need to unpack the individual parameters; therefore `with()` unpacks `shape` and `scale` from the named vector `params` input.

`gamma_fit_error()` returns the distance between the data `x` at the 50% and 95% quantiles and the calculated values at those quantiles using the gamma distribution parameters.  `dist()` finds the distance between the rows, which is why one needs to `t()` transpose the values from column-wise matrix to row-wise.  Because `dist()` returns a matrix, we use the `c()` shorthand to convert it into a vector.

Outputs:

```r
> opt
$par
     shape      scale 
 0.9765883 74.5730641 

$value
[1] 0.007629429

$counts
function gradient 
     250      250 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

> with(as.list(opt$par), pgamma(x, shape = shape, scale = scale))
      q50       q95 
0.4999896 0.9499950

> with(as.list(opt$par), offset + qgamma(expected, shape = shape, scale = scale))
[1] 130.0015 300.0075

> x + offset
q50 q95 
130 300

> hist(with(as.list(opt$par), offset + rgamma(1e4, shape = shape, scale = scale)))
```

[image: histogram of the gamma distribution]