# How to determine the initial points of the maximum likelihood method

Tags: r, mle

I'm currently working on distribution fitting. I used `fitdistr` function, but having problem in determining the initial points for the MLE. For example, I want to fit my data (rainfall- 13149 by 1 matrix) with gamma distribution.

```
fit.gamma = fitdistr(rainfall,dgamma,start=list(shape = ?, scale = ?),method="Nelder-Mead")
```

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266354/how-can-i-estimate-the-shape-and-scale-of-a-gamma-dist-with-a-particular-mean-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `fitdistrplus` is very good for this.  It will guess gamma parameters for you if you don't have starting values.  Also, you can use method of moments if your guesses fail.

```
x <- rgamma(100, 0.5, 0.5)

library(fitdistrplus)
(pars <- fitdist(x, "gamma"))
# Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#        estimate Std. Error
# shape 0.4443304 0.05131369
# rate  0.5622472 0.10644511
```

Comment: Thank you Legalizelt.. I have found several packages for this purpose including fitdistrplus, but confused which is the best. Do you mean using methods of moments to find the starting values?

Comment: @Legalizelt I have to do some research on the starting values and I don't know if there are some methods to find the optimal starting points that would give the best results of estiamtion.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the helpful responds @Legalizelt